# How can I make enumitem's setlist command apply to compactitem?

Tags: lists, itemize, paralist

I'm writing a paper using the `compactitem` environment from the [`paralist` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/paralist). I want to use something other than bullets as a default list item indicator; now, this:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=$\star$}
```

works fine - for `itemize` lists. But what do I do for `compactitem`? The following:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[compactitem,1]{label=$\star$}
```

produces an error message. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[compactitem,1]{label=$\star$}
\begin{document}
\begin{compactitem}
    \item Hello
    \item World
\end{itemize}
\end{compactitem}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt fails because lists in the `paralist` package are not responsive to `enumitem` mechanism for customizations; instead, you can easily emulate `compactitem` using `enumitem`: kill the vertical spacing with `nolistsep` and now you can use all `enumitem` features. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{compitem}{itemize}{4}
\setlist[compitem,1]{nolistsep,label=$\star$}

\begin{document}

Some test text
\begin{compitem}
\item First.
\item Second.
\item Third.
\end{compitem}
Some test text

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you decide to stick to `paralist` you need to use

```
\setdefaultitem{$\star$}{}{}{}
```

provide the other arguments as desired.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}

\setdefaultitem{$\star$}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

Some test text
\begin{compactitem}
\item First.
\item Second.
\item Third.
\end{compactitem}
Some test text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So, essentially you're suggesting I not use paralist...

Comment: @einpoklum what I am primarily suggesting is not using `enumitem` commands for `paralist` lists; in any case, I think `enumitem` is more powerful and offer you more possibilities than `paralist`, so in a sese, yes, I'd suggest you to use `enumitem`.

Comment: Is there someplace (e.g. an answer here on the site) which covers how to emulate all, or mostly-all, of `paralist`'s functionality with `enumitem`?

Comment: In any case, you can easily achieve what you want also with paralist; I added this to my updated answer.

Comment: @einpoklum Regarding the question in your previous comment, no, I'm not aware of a place or answer covering that, but it shouldn't be difficult to do it. Maybe a topic for a new question?